# HashMap Serializability

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

HashMap implements the Serializable interface; so it can be serialized. I have looked at the implementation of HashMap and the Entry[] table is marked as transient. Since the Entry[] table is the one that stores the entire contents of the Map and if it cannot be serialized, how is the Map constructed back during de-serialization

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you look at [the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html) you will see that it does not rely on the default serialization mechanism, but manually writes out all the entries (as an alternating stream of keys and values):

```
/**
  * Save the state of the <tt>HashMap</tt> instance to a stream (i.e.,
  * serialize it)
  *
  * @serialData The <i>capacity</i> of the HashMap (the length of the
  *             bucket array) is emitted (int), followed by the
  *             <i>size</i> (an int, the number of key-value
  *             mappings), followed by the key (Object) and value (Object)
  *             for each key-value mapping.  The key-value mappings are
  *             emitted in no particular order.
  */
      private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
             throws IOException
         {
             Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> i =
                 (size > 0) ? entrySet0().iterator() : null;

            // Write out the threshold, loadfactor, and any hidden stuff
            s.defaultWriteObject();

            // Write out number of buckets
            s.writeInt(table.length);

            // Write out size (number of Mappings)
            s.writeInt(size);

            // Write out keys and values (alternating)
            if (i != null) {
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
                    s.writeObject(e.getKey());
                    s.writeObject(e.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
```

This is more compact than the array, which can contain many empty entries and link chains and overhead for Map$Entry wrappers.

Note that it still invokes `defaultWriteObject` for the "easy" fields. In order for that to work, it has to mark everything else as `transient`.

Comment: I find it interesting that the load factor of HashMap is not serialized. So this information is getting lost.

Comment: @PeterWippermann: Are you sure? This `loadFactor` is not transient, it should be contained in the output produced by `defaultWriteObject`. (In fact, the comment in the source right before the call to defaultWriteObject directly mentions this).

Comment: Oh you're right of course! I didn't notice, that it would be affected by the default serialisation. Thanks for pointing me to this! :-)

Answer (score 10):

`HashMap` takes care of its own serialization through the use of the `writeObject` and `readObject` methods.

Answer (score 4):

HashMaps don't serialize their Entry objects during serialization. Take a look at its `writeObject` method.

The javadocs explain:

> The capacity of the HashMap (the length of the bucket array) is
>   emitted (int), followed by the size (an int, the number of key-value
>   mappings), followed by the key (Object) and value (Object) for each
>   key-value mapping. The key-value mappings are emitted in no particular
>   order.

If you look at the `readObject` method you will see how the Entry table is rebuilt using the size, keys and values.