# Serialize HashMap<String, Object> in Java

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

I am trying to serialise an object of the type `HashMap<String, Object>`. However, I get `NotSerializableException` at runtime. Here is the code that I use for serialization

```
public void WriteModel(String modelFile, HashMap<String, Object> o) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (modelFile));
        os.writeObject(o);
        os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println ("Error in saving model " + modelFile + ": " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The HashMap has either an `int` as value or an object of the following type

```
public class suggestMenu implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8558253517294665710L;
    public List<Integer> suggestions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int freq = 0; 
}
```

So basically all of the objects contained in HashMap are serializable.
What is it that I am doing wrong? Has it something to do with the fact that HashMap contains more than one type?
And what could be the possible way of serializing it, given that it is almost impossible to change its structure?

Here is the full stacktrace of the error

```
Error in saving model /home/ritesh/Documents/spell-checker/dict_ser.ser: java.io.NotSerializableException: spell.SpellCheckTrainer
java.io.NotSerializableException: spell.SpellCheckTrainer
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at spell.SpellCheckTrainer.WriteModel(SpellCheckTrainer.java:254)
at spell.SpellCheckTrainer.CreateDictionary(SpellCheckTrainer.java:246)
at spell.SpellCheckTrainer.main(SpellCheckTrainer.java:55)
```

Comment: this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103611/hashmap-serializability

Comment: @ritesh it says `spell.SpellCheckTrainer`, is this class serializable?

Comment: I have a hunch: one of the values in the map is an inner class, which implicitly contains a reference to its enclosing class `SpellCheckTrainer`, which isn't serializable. Solution: use a static nested class instead. Don't serialize inner classes.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Thanks for pointing to the post! It helps me in better understanding HashMap's serialization process but I still do not quite understand why is it failing in this case and how could

Comment: @ritesh every class being serialized has to be serializable.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, No SpellCheckTrainer is not serializable. So that is why it is failing. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @StuartMarks Yes you are absolutely right! I shall make that into a static class. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.io.NotSerializableException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895867/java-io-notserializableexception)

Answer (score 0):

HashMap can be serialized, but you have Object as values. These Objects might be **NOT** serializbale like your SpellCheckTrainer class. Make that class serializable you might be fine. Note: Sonarqube code analysis would still mark this as a CRITICAL issue with squid:S1948